# How to change the Filter Value in Drupal Views Query Alter For Paragraph value in Drupal8?

Tags: view, drupal-9

[My View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukT4L.png) 
[Check This Image First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFURn.png)
[My Filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMqaR.png)

Hello all I am trying to change this highlight field value using hook_views_query_alter....but I am unable to do... Can Someone Help me on this Query Alteration I am writing this code but it's not working

```
    foreach ($query->where as &$condition_group) {
            foreach ($condition_group['conditions'] as &$condition) {
            if ($condition['field'] == 'paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_recommendation_tagging__paragraph__field_recommendation_tag.field_recommendation_tag_target_id') {
              $condition = [
                'value' => $rec_tags,
                'operator' => 'in',
              ];
            }
           }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all do you enter in your condition?
Verify the fieldname :

> paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_recommendation_tagging__paragraph__field_recommendation_tag.field_recommendation_tag_target_id

If you enter in your condition don't forget to re-add you field in your condition and that your value correspond to the right id :

```
foreach ($query->where as $condition_group) {
        foreach ($condition_group['conditions'] as $condition) {
        if ($condition['field'] === $field_name ) {
          $condition = [
            'field' => $field_name,
            'value' => $rec_tags,
            'operator' => 'in',
          ];
        }
       }
      }
```